# "Received exception event aura:systemError from server" while uploading 1mb file in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning

Im trying to upload a 1mb File in salesforce lightning component referring this documentation by Peter(http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/)
I am able to upload 500KB files using this code, but when I try to upload a 1mb file, i get this error from the server call which is made to the apex class 
**ERROR "Received exception event aura:systemError from server"** Any help would be appreciated. Im using the larger file approach of the above mentioned documentation(CHUNK_SIZE)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error. 
I solved it changing the chunk size from 950000 to 750000